# Laravel 6: Server error messages when uploading images with TinyMCE 5

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I followed the documentation on the website: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/

My script:

```
tinymce.init({
        // OTHER SETTINGS
        images_upload_url: '{{ asset('postAcceptor.blade.php') }}',
        images_upload_credentials: true,
    });
```

My postAcceptor file follows the example of the documentation, with some obvious modifications like:

```
 $imageFolder = "{{ asset('uploads/') }}";
```

The postAcceptor seems to return a valid json array with the correct location of the file to write.
But my console says something like "impossible to move temp file X to location Y" and
I receive different server errors depending on how I tweak the code. I have also added a CSRF token via the images_upload_handler. I have also tried to target the "storage" folder in my Laravel project. I'm open to any suggestions.

I think I'm missing something more basic, but cannot understand what...

Any working example code from a Laravel 5 or 6 project would help!

Comment: Have you given appropriate permission to write in location Y?

Comment: You mean in my config filesystems?

Comment: In your operating system

Comment: Yes, it's just local storage. But thanks for the answer.